# Implementing alpha equivalence - Haskell

Tags: haskell

So let me define a few things:

```
type Name = String

data Exp = Var Name 
         | App Exp Exp
         | Lam Name Exp
  deriving (Eq,Show,Read)
```

I want to define `alpha-equivalence`, which is

```
alpha_eq :: Exp -> Exp -> Bool
-- The terms x and y are not alpha-equivalent, because they are not bound in a lambda abstraction 
alpha_eq (Var x) (Var y) = False
alpha_eq (Lam x e1) (Lam y e2) = False
alpha_eq (App e1 e2) (App e3 e4) = False
```

For example `Lam "x" (Var "x")` and `Lam "y" (Var "y")` are both equivalent. However I'm both new and horrible at `Haskell`. Could someone give a clue of how to implement `alpha_eq`? One thing I thought about was to use `Map Name Int` so in this case I would have:

```
['x' -> 0] ['y' -> 0]
```

so in this case `Map['x'] == Map['y']`. But again I'm horrible at Haskell. Could you someone give me a clue how to implement it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, using a `Map` a correct idea (though think on what the key and value types should be; with `Map Name Int` you need two extra arguments instead of one). You need to add it as the argument of a helper function, I won't give the full implementation since you asked for a clue only:

```
alpha_eq e1 e2 = alpha_eq' e1 e2 env0 where
  env0 = ???
  alpha_eq' (Var x) (Var y) env = ???
  alpha_eq' (Lambda x e1) (Lambda y e2) env = ???
  alpha_eq' (App e1 e2) (App e3 e4) env = ???
  -- you don't want to throw an error in all other cases
  alpha_eq' _ _ env = ???
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also make separate function `subst :: Name -> Exp -> Exp -> Exp`. Then, `alpha_eq` Lam-case becomes

```
alpha_eq :: Exp -> Exp -> Bool
...
alpha_eq (Lam x xb) (Lam y yb) = xb `alpha_eq` subst y (Var x) yb
...
```

Excersise: figure out other `alpha_eq` cases and implementation of `subst`.

Comment: The substitution approach will fail on: `Lam "x" (Var "x")` and `Lam "y" (Var "x")`. It will report that these 2 are equivalent, while they are not

Comment: So, to fix this we can replace each name with unique one.

Comment: All I am saying that it leads us to the concept of "capture-avoiding substitution" which is well described in the literature and worth looking at in the context of this question.